# Table comparison cell content reference from non cell array object

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have two tables with same variables. One table contain one row while other table contain more than one rows.

```
    a=[1 2; 2 3],b=[2 3; 1 2]
     S1=table(a,b)
    a=[1 1],b=[1 1]
    S2=table(a,b)
    if all(S2{:,:}<S1{:,:}) & any(S2{:,:}<=S1{:,:})
    S1=[S1;S2]
    end
```

Where is the mistake in specifying table or cell?  Even the conversion table2cell, table2struct, table2array did not work (getvar error was shown).

Table values are fixed. There is no addition, no replacement, but the appending only when the condition is satisfied. Final output is table with values as shown.

```
S1 = 3×2 table 
  a        b
______ ______ 
 1 2       2 3
 2 3       1 2 
 1 1       1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you are trying to compare two set of data (`S1` and `S2`) that have different size.

```
S2{:,:}
     1     1     1     1
S1{:,:}
     1     2     2     3
     2     3     1     2
```

If you want to compare each row of `S1` against `S2` you can use the function [bsxfun](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

to check `S2 < S1`

```
bsxfun(@lt,S2{:,:},S1{:,:})
```

to check `S2 <= S1`

```
bsxfun(@le,S2{:,:},S1{:,:})
```

This will lead to:

```
if all(bsxfun(@lt,S2{:,:},S1{:,:})) & any(bsxfun(@le,S2{:,:},S1{:,:}))
   S1=[S1;S2]
end
```